# Detect auto fill in a text input on react native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to detect when a user uses auto fill on a text input in react native.

I have a login form and I want to submit the login if they autofill the fields for example from the keychain.

I would love something like onAutoFill but there doesn't seem to be anything like that.

```
<TextInput onChange={setEmail} autoComplete="email" />
<TextInput onChange={setPassword} autoComplete="password" secureTextEntry={true} />
```

I've tried looking at the onChange event but there doesn't seem to be any hint that a change comes from autofill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with a bit of a workaround since there is no native event.

Here we submit the form if the previous value was empty and the new one is atleast the minimum password length.

```
  onChangeText={(newValue) => {
    onChange(newValue);

    // NOTE since our passwords must be atleast 8 characters if the field changes by 8 characters and was empty we can assume it was autofilled
    if (value.length === 0 && newValue.length >= 8) {
      onSubmit();
    }
  }}
```

Comment: genius actually!